# toggle jquery - issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rXYA9/1/)

However the mouse over when dragged to left or right  stops  the toogle.
The hover() event didn't solve the problem.

Any idea ?

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

#show {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -2px;
    position: absolute;
}

<div id="show"></div>

<div class="fileinputs">Visible Panel Div</div>

$('#show').mouseover(function() {
    $('.fileinputs').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you want the div to show onmouseover and then hide onmouseout?

Comment: exactly. The hover() event works correctly only if the divs are not overlapping.

Comment: You should put `div.fileinputs` inside the element because otherwise jQuery thinks that it is a new element http://jsfiddle.net/rXYA9/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you want to simply show the element on mouseover and then hide it on mouseout, you should also use `mouseout()` to define the desired behavior you want when the mouse is removed:

```
$("#show")
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(".fileinputs").toggle();
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(".fileinputs").toggle();
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rXYA9/8/). (It's choppy because `fileinputs` is a separate element, and it's not counting hovering over that as hovering over the show div).

But you should use hover, just to make it easier:

```
$("#show").hover(function(){
    $(".fileinputs").show();
}, function(){
    $(".fileinputs").hide();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rXYA9/9/). (Choppy for the same reason as above).

Since your desired behavior is definite, we'll just use `show()` for when the mouse is over it and `hide()` when it is removed.

By the way, it is preferred that you bind events using `delegate()` (for older versions of jQuery) or `on()` (for jQuery 1.7+):

```
$(document).on("mouseover mouseout", "#show", function(){
    $(".fileinputs").toggle();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rXYA9/10/).

Though, you really should just use CSS for this. You can place `fileinputs` inside of `show` and use a child selector:

```
#show:hover > .fileinputs {
    display: block;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rXYA9/11/). This one doesn't flicker because the element is inside the one that's getting the hover declarations attached to it, and CSS considers it as though you are still hovering over the parent element (because you technically are, as the target of the hover is within the boundaries of the parent [it would still work if it was outside the boundaries because the element is still nested]).

Comment: +1 but do you know why this is choppy?  I would think this would work smoothly http://jsfiddle.net/rXYA9/12/

Comment: @AdamRackis: Smells like a conflict again with separation of elements. I don't think Javascript works exactly like CSS in terms of hover events on parents that follow through when you hover over children. Though, curiously, adding `mouseout` to the events in the `on()` function makes it work smoothly. Can't really explain it further...I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you set your z-index on show to be -2.  Once the fileInputs div is visible, it becomes **on top of** show, and as a result, mouseover for show no longer responds.

If you notice, if you hover from left to right over the red show div, but just below where the text is, the `fileinputs` div does in fact toggle.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a border around the `fileinputs` div, the cause of the behavior will be clearer.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pS9L8/

Moving your cursor over the region where the two divs overlap triggers a mouseover event, showing the hidden `fileinputs` div. Since that div is now displayed on top of `show`, your cursor is no longer directly over the original `show` div. You then continue to move your cursor, and as it moves outside the `fileinputs` region, that move is seen as *another* entrance to the underlying `show` div. Which again triggers the `.toggle()`, re-hiding the `fileinputs` div.

One quick fix is to switch to the jQuery custom event [`mouseEnter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of `mouseover` (although you may get some jerky artifacts as jQuery reasons about the meaning of "over"). Depending on what you're trying to achieve, another option would be to reorder the two divs by z-index.